# How to enable boost library in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, fibers

I have a problem with adding boost library to my project in Xcode.
It seems that some parts of boost work correctly but when I use some of them I get the following errors.
Example- boost fiber library:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "boost::fibers::future_category()", referenced from:
      std::make_error_code(boost::fibers::future_errc) in main.o
  "boost::fibers::condition_variable_any::notify_all()", referenced from:
      boost::fibers::condition_variable::notify_all() in main.o
  "boost::fibers::mutex::lock()", referenced from:
      std::__1::unique_lock<boost::fibers::mutex>::unique_lock(boost::fibers::mutex&) in main.o
  "boost::fibers::mutex::unlock()", referenced from:
      std::__1::unique_lock<boost::fibers::mutex>::unlock() in main.o
      std::__1::unique_lock<boost::fibers::mutex>::~unique_lock() in main.o
  "boost::fibers::wait_queue::empty() const", referenced from:
      boost::fibers::condition_variable_any::~condition_variable_any() in main.o
      boost::fibers::mutex::~mutex() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you failed telling how you installed boost

Comment: Some parts of boost are header only. Others require you to link to libraries.

Comment: I install boost with brew

Comment: But after downloading zip unpacking and building the same thing happens. It works with header only parts.

Comment: Did you tell your Xcode project to _link_ against the boost libraries (they might be `.a`, they might be `.dylib`, I don't actually know).  One way to do this (probably not the official way) is to add them to 'Other Linker Flags'.

Comment: I already did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to manually add the library file in your Xcode. For instance, you were using `boost/fiber`, then you should at least add the corresponding library file `libboost_fiber-mt.dylib` in your Xcode project. The file should be located in `hombrew/lib`. And to add it, you can simply drag it to `Targets->General->Frameworks and Libraries`:

[image]

---

This should solve the majority of undefined symbol problems. Depends on your project, you might also want to add other libraries, such as `libboost_context` and `libboost_filesystem` to your project as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install boost on a macOS from my experience is to install homebrew package manager. Then in a terminal enter brew install boost, this will install the boost library for you on your machine. To enable boost in Xcode open project then navigate to build setting from there select header search path and paste the location of the boost header files. (usually located in the usr/local/include) for the header and usually located in the usr/local/lib) for the library files. [How to enable boost in xcode](http://neutrofoton.github.io/blog/2016/03/27/configure-boost-c-plus-plus-on-xcode/#:%7E:text=includes%20Boost%20libraries.-,Xcode,-To%20include%20Boost)

Comment: I did this both ways- by brew and manually. @Ranoiaetep's answer solved my problem